# Creating css full screen layout

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

Endles trying to create a css layout

```
<div id="act"><img src="img/home01.jpg"></div>    
<div id="buttons></div>
```

img "home01" should fit the screen. No scrolls, no whitespaces, no overflows, whatever is the monitor size and whatever is the img original size.

div buttons should be available for clicking, i.e. in front of the img "home01" (higher z-index) and centered hor&ver on the screen.
Please help.

Comment: Have you tried position absolute?

Comment: Yes i tried absolute, relative, fixed, margins and paddings 0 z-index...

Comment: should the image always fit the screen ratio? So that an overflow occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div id="act">
    <div id="buttons">
        <button>test1</button>
        <button>test2</button> 
        <button>test3</button> 
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>



#act {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url( "http://hdwallpaperpics.com/wallpaper/picture/image/Opera-Background-Blue-Swirls.jpg" );
}
#buttons {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: @ Igor i cant place "buttons" inside the "act" because innerHTML of "act will be changed dinamically (by clicking on buttons)

Comment: You can innerHTML to #content

Comment: You can innerHTML to #content - ?? there is no #content on page

Comment: <div id="content"></div> look at the site: jsfiddle.net/5Sa2S/1 in red border

Answer (score 5):

First you have to set style to your div id="act" to cover whole screen
like

```
#act{
    position:absolute;
    left:0; top:0; right:0; bottom:0;
    height:100%; width:100%;
}
```

Now, there is image inside your div, so set style to that image like

```
img { min-width:100%;min-height:100%; }
```

Comment: Isn't the use of `left:0` and `right:0` together useless ? (same for top/bottom)

Comment: If we use width:100% and height:100% then only left and top needed. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: It's useless even without `width: 100%`. You're asking to set a div "at 0px from left border, AND at 0px from right border". One will surely be overrided (it seems left > right), I guess

Comment: you can try it your self, i u give left and right 0px without width, then also it works.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried width:100%? If the img is a background image (tileable) use background: url('img/home01.jpg') repeat-x
The buttons should be over the image? then you should change your html a little bit. Put them inside the first div. CLOSE the img tag, if you really need it.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bCtf2/)

Comment: @ Pablo, i cant place "buttnos" inside the "act" because innerHTML of "act will be changed dinamically (by clicking on buttons)

Comment: Then absolute or fixed position the buttons

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/ZpvsC/

**HTML**

```
<div id="act"><img src="http://images.travelpod.com/tripwow/photos/ta-00ad-668e-a3e6/night-gondeliers-venice-italy%2B1152_12878015263-tpfil02aw-3646.jpg"></div>    
<div id="buttons">
     <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Ipsum</li>
        <li>Dolor</li>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Ipsum</li>
        <li>Dolor</li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#act img{width:100%; overflow:hidden; position:relative;}
#buttons{position:absolute; z-index:999; top:20px; right:5%; color:#fff; display:block;}
#buttons li{display:inline-block; margin:0 5px 0 0;}
```

​